# iOS/Cocoa Data Controller Class - is this standard practice?

Tags: ios, class, cocoa-touch, controller

I've completed the first two online tutorials "Your First iOS App" and "Your Second iOS App". The latter makes use of a data controller class as seen [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/DesigningDataModel/DesigningDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH3-SW2).

I'm now making my way through "iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide 3rd Edition". It seemingly makes no reference to data controller classes, however, and seems to be putting methods into the model class itself (i.e., into `MyClass.m`, not `MyClassDataController.m`).

I'm sure all will become clear eventually, but can someone give me a wider frame of reference? Is the use of a data controller class just a stylistic decision? I've looked in a couple of other books and they don't seem to refer to data controllers, either.

Comment: Till it works, don't worry too much about the structure :) If you have nice separated classes for the model and the presentation, and you write readable code that makes sense, you're on the right track. As you become more and more experienced, you'll eventually recognize common patterns and best practices easier. Just a bit of time and effort, nothing else :)

Comment: Since I don't have the book, I can't say whether the book is misleading you or just taking pedagogical shortcuts that will be expanded upon later.  But I see that there's a forum for the book (http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewforum.php?f=211), and that Joe Conway (one of the authors) seems to post there fairly often. So you might want to try asking there.

Comment: I get it now. The data controller class in "My Second iOS App" is just a class for the array object (mutable) that holds pointers to all the MyClass objects (BirdWatching, actually). The term DataContoller sounded so similar to ViewController that I thought it was a more official beast than it actually is! Thanks, all.

Comment: In later chapters, you will have data controllers.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks. I suspected as much, but they're not listed in the index and a cursory flick through didn't help me :)

Comment: Sure, it wouldn't be in the index since, for whatever reason, the term "data controller" isn't too common in Cocoa (although any Cocoa developer should understand what you mean by it). When you get there in the Homepwner project of the BNR book, `PossessionStore` will your data controller. When you start using Core Data, Apple has framework classes that are data controllers, and that may be what they are gearing you up to in their tutorials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a great question! To be honest, both approaches are acceptable. Aaron Hillegrass (who co-authors the BNR books) is a very well respected developer (who even used to train Apple engineers), and obviously the Apple sample code you looked at is 'from the horse's mouth', so to speak.

Why does Apple suggest you use a separate data controller in their app? Well, if your data controller conforms to the relevant protocols you could plug it straight into something like a `UITableView`. If you were writing a universal iPad / iPhone app that had different views for the two devices then this could be quite useful. This is also quite useful if you're working with storyboards. As Apple say:

> A data controller class allows other objects in the app to access objects [...] without needing to know anything about how the data model is implemented.

But this can be overkill: there are plenty of apps that *don't* use this pattern, and they throw that logic into the view controller itself. There are pros and cons to both. To put it another way: as you navigate around the sample code Apple put on their developer website you'll find plenty of apps that *don't* follow the pattern Apple suggest in the 'Your Second iOS App' tutorial!

Comment: Thanks for your help, and your reassurance that it wasn't a ridiculous query :) The fact that it potentially gels well with the various demands of iPhone and iPad views is useful to know.

Comment: Another use case is to support both OS X and iOS with minimal changes to your data management code, although this isn't nearly as common a requirement.

Comment: Is there any specific example you would like to share .. please

Comment: What do you mean by 'specific example' - with regards to sharing code between iOS and OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as an intermediate way of separating Data (the Model) from Controllers and Views.

A good exercise, once you get further inte the (excellent, IMHO) BNR book is to rewrite the Birdwatching example using Core Data instead of the Data Controllers.

It's not much work - (I've done it), and you'll get a better understanding of Core Data if you actually try to use it for something as simple as this.

Good luck.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I may well do that! Thanks for your help.